# Problems with back and go to next activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, back

I use intent to go to other Activity

This is my way: Activity A -> B -> C -> D -> E.

When i press Back, it go E -> D -> C-> B-> A

but, in Activity E, when press Back, i want to come back to C, so i use

```
mIntent.setClass(E.this, C.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

My problems is: When i come to C from E, i press back, it come back to E. But i want to come back to B like C-> B-> A.

In my opinion, when i use above code, i create new Activity C, so i cant come back to Activity B

How can i solve it?

Thanks you so much

Comment: The question is what should happen when you're on D and press the back button?

Comment: Are you overriding the back button for this or not?

Comment: D back to C .......... i overriding the back button

Comment: You can create a flag in the activities to track where the flow came from. You can then over ride the backbutton to take to the appropriate activity based on that flag value. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `finish()`  on D when you move to E, this will remove them from the stack and cause E to go to C. Your stack will look like E, C, B, A because D is removed.

Comment: But if i am on E, when i want to go to B. i must finish() D and C. So what should happen when i am on D and press the back button? -> go to B, not C???

Comment: if you call finish on C when moving to B, then hitting the back button in C will bring you to B. Basically, if you don't want an activity to be on the stack when backing up in the app, call finish on it when you call the next activity.

Comment: When i have A-> B -> C -> D ->E, if i use your method look like A-> B -> C (finish) -> D (finish) -> E . I can go back from E -> B. But When i am in D (before finish and call E), i press Back, go to to B, not C???

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your  your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, `android:noHistory="true"` attribute in D activity tag

Comment: But if from D call other activity F? so F can not comeback to D

Comment: can u edit ur question to show the flow of activities from A to F wit if conditions???